# How to use script and noscript as a component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this code:

```
<script>
 (function () {
    alert('Hi');
    var element = document.createElement('script');
    element.type = 'text/javascript';
    element.async = true;
    element.src = '//... .js';
    var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    script.parentNode.insertBefore(element, script);
 })();
</script>

<noscript>
   <img src="//..." width="1" height="1" style="display: none;" />
</noscript>
```

I want to put this code inside of an angular component, so I could call this component from any other component and make the script execute.

How can I do this?

I read a lot of ways to solve this, but I didn't find the right thing to do.

Comment: Hmm.. If JavaScript is not available, how would the component even be loaded in the first place

Comment: @wentjun — Server side rendering I assume

Comment: I thought of loading this script on the fly inside the ts file of the component (on init), or something like that..

Comment: It is SSR, I use angular universal

Comment: write your script in index.html it's work proper

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new DOM element `script` in `head` tag of document with code below :

```
let node = document.createElement('script');
node.src = ...;
node.type = 'text/javascript';
node.charset = 'utf-8';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
```

Pay attention, to execute this code only once. (inside a single instance service for example). 
And also it's a best practice to check if `document` exists.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScriptService {
  constructor() {
    // call once, because of 'providedIn: root' => singleton instance
    if (document) {
      // browser platform
      let node = document.createElement('script');
      node.src = ...;
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.charset = 'utf-8';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, inject singleton service inside your component :

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(
    private scriptService: ScriptService
  ) { }
}
```

When your component will be instantiated for the first time, `ScriptService` will be instantiated also, but only once, and your `script` element will be added to `document`.

Comment: Hey thank you! The thing is that I dont have ```src```, I have this chunk of code (I have tried to put it inside js file but I couldn't use it in the src.